# How to send a .deb file from jenkins Pipeline to Spinnaker Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, spinnaker

I have a jenkins Pipeline that results with a build artifact which is a `deb` file.

[image]

I was planning to use that deb file to fill in the Package option in the Bake Configuration Phase.

[image]

It doesn't work and results in

[image: Error]

How should I go about doing this?

I guess I need to transfer artifact from the spinnaker pipeline's build trigger(the Jenkins pipeline) but I don't understand how to do that.

Is [this](https://spinnaker.io/reference/artifacts/from-build-triggers/) of any use? I can't wrap my head around what they want me to do in order to send the file.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done so far looks correct, so we need to debug why it fails.
You have to look at the source of the execution that fails (press the "source" link). This json structure is the execution context (you probably want to install a json formatter plugin in your browser or something to read it). Navigate to `trigger.artifacts` and look for the artifact there. If you find it, please post the result here.
I think maybe the issue is the name of the deb file. It should have been named like `simplenodeappinstaller_1.0-0_amd64.deb`. A simple solution is to add the jenkins build number or a timestamp as the release number.

You can also try to activate the artifact decorator (set `artifact.decorator.enabled: true` in `igor-local.yml`. This will cause Igor to parse deb and rpm files in a more sensible way, IMHO. See below for more info.

Another thing is that Jenkins sometimes puts all test results and other stuff into the artifacts list, and I think the default maximum number of artifacts returned are 20. This is however configurable under the key `BuildArtifactFilter.maxArtifacts` (see https://github.com/spinnaker/igor/blob/master/igor-web/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/igor/build/BuildArtifactFilter.java). Reading the code, it also seems deb-files should already be prioritized over other kinds of artifacts, so I don't really think this is the issue.

### Decorator primer

Enabling the artifact decorator will convert this artifact:

```js
fileName: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
displayPath: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
relativePath: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
```

into

```js
fileName: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
displayPath: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
relativePath: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
reference: "openmotif22-libs-2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64.rpm"
name: "openmotif22-libs"
type: "rpm"
version: "2.2.4-192.1.3.x86_64"
decorated: "true"
```

The built in decorator supports `deb` and `rpm`, but it can be extended using config like this:

```yaml
artifact:
#  This is a feature toggle for decoration of artifacts.
  decorator:
    enabled: true
    fileDecorators:
       - type: docker/image
         decoratorRegex: '(.+):(.+)'
         identifierRegex: '(.+\/.+:.+)'
```